# NetBeans cannot enable JavaFX 2 Support

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I am trying to develop a JavaFX application using NetBeans (or any IDE for that matter), and cannot wrap my head around properly installing the JDK AND JavaFX.

For context, I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and following [this guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-java). Currently when running `java -version` I get this output:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_272"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_272-8u272-b10-0ubuntu1~18.04-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.272-b10, mixed mode)
```

This is not the JDK I would like to be using. I have downloaded the JDK 15 from [this website](https://jdk.java.net/15/), opened the tar.gz file and put it in `/usr/lib/jvm/` in a folder called `jdk-15`. Once the folder was extracted, I added the JDK to my system PATH variables:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

This is followed by a system restart. In NetBeans, I add the JDK-15 directory as a Java Platform, and yet under the JavaFX tab I still see "Cannot Enable JavaFX Support".

What am I missing? From following the OpenJFX documentation, it seems that upon assigning the PATH / JAVA_HOME variables I should be able to at least see JDK 15 when calling `java -version` but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

JDK 15 from Oracle and most OpenJDK builds of Java 8 do not include JavaFX.  Try one of the OpenJDK builds from Azul or BellSoft that includes JavaFX.

https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk

https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-15-current

Also when you attempt to enable the JavaFX support in NetBeans - look for information in the var/log/messages.log from the user dir mentioned in the NetBeans About box.